# ¿Cómo funcionan construcciones y destrucciones de variables en c++?

Tags: c++

He solamente apprendido java y C. Es la primera vez que hizo frente a destructor y manejo de la memoria. Tengo un codigo de declaración, definición y utilización de una clase A :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;
class A {
    private : int x, y;
    public :
        A();                 // constructor I
        A(int abs);          // constructor II
        A(int abs, int ord); // constructor III
        A(const A &) ;       // constructor IV
        ~A() ;              // destructeur
        void affiche();
} ;
A::A()
{
    x = 1 ;  y = 0 ;
    cout << "constructor I             : " << x << " " << y <<endl ;
}

A::A(int abs)
{
    x = abs ;  y = 0 ;
    cout << "constructor II            : " << x << " " << y <<endl ;
}
A::A(int abs, int ord)
{
    x = abs ;  y = ord ;
    cout << "constructor III           : " << x << " " << y << endl ;
}

A::A (const A & a)
{
    cout << "constructor IV (de copie) : " << a.x << " " << a.y << endl ;
    x = a.x ;  y = a.y ;
}

A::~A ()
{
    cout << "destrucción                : " << x << " " << y << endl ;
}

void A::affiche()
{
    cout << "punto de coordenadas  : " << x << " " << y <<endl;
}

void fct (A, A*) ;        // prototype fonction indépendante fct

main ()
{
    cout << "entrada main" << endl ;
    A a;
    A b(2);
    A c(10,20);
    A d = a ;
    A * adr = new A (3,3) ;
    fct (a, adr) ;
    A e(30,40);
    A tab[6]={4,c,0,e};
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    tab[i].affiche();
    cout << "fin main" << endl ;
}

void fct (A d, A * add)
{
    cout << "entrada fct" << endl ;
    delete add ;
    cout << "salida fct" << endl ;
}
```

Pensaba que me daría el  código siguiente :

```
entrada main
constructor I             : 1 0
constructor II            : 2 0
constructor III           : 10 20
constructor IV (de copie) : 1 0
constructor III           : 3 3
entrada fct
destrucción                : 3 3
salida fct
constructor III           : 30 40
constructor II            : 4 0
constructor IV (de copie) : 10 20
constructor II            : 0 0
constructor IV (de copie) : 30 40
constructor I             : 0 0
constructor I             : 0 0
punto de coordenadas  : 4 0
punto de coordenadas  : 10 20
punto de coordenadas  : 0 0
punto de coordenadas  : 30 40
punto de coordenadas  : 0 0
punto de coordenadas  : 0 0
fin main
```

Pero me da :

```
entrada main
constructor I             : 1 0
constructor II            : 2 0
constructor III           : 10 20
constructor IV (de copie) : 1 0
constructor III           : 3 3
constructor IV (de copie) : 1 0 (Oh?)
entrada fct
destrucción                : 3 3
salida fct
destrucción                : 1 0 (Oh?)
constructor III           : 30 40
constructor II            : 4 0
constructor IV (de copie) : 10 20
constructor II            : 0 0
constructor IV (de copie) : 30 40
constructor I             : 1 0
constructor I             : 1 0
punto de coordenadas  : 4 0
punto de coordenadas  : 10 20
punto de coordenadas  : 0 0
punto de coordenadas  : 30 40
punto de coordenadas  : 1 0
punto de coordenadas  : 1 0
fin main
destrucción                : 1 0 (Oh?)
destrucción                : 1 0 (Oh?)
destrucción                : 30 40 (Oh?)
destrucción                : 0 0 (Oh?)
destrucción                : 10 20 (Oh?)
destrucción                : 4 0 (Oh?)
destrucción                : 30 40 (Oh?)
destrucción                : 1 0 (Oh?)
destrucción                : 10 20 (Oh?)
destrucción                : 2 0 (Oh?)
destrucción                : 1 0 (Oh?)
```

Entonces, porque hay estas diferencias :

- `A * adr = new A (3,3) ;`

que crea un nuevo objeto pero también su copia.

```
constructor IV (de copie) : 1 0 (Oh?)
```

- `fct (a, adr) ;`

Que destruye `adr` en la función pero también destruye `a` cuando la  termina :

```
destrucción : 1 0 (Oh?)
```

Por la misma manera detruye las variables cuando termina el programo...

```
destrucción                : 1 0 (Oh?)
destrucción                : 1 0 (Oh?)
destrucción                : 30 40 (Oh?)
destrucción                : 0 0 (Oh?)
destrucción                : 10 20 (Oh?)
destrucción                : 4 0 (Oh?)
destrucción                : 30 40 (Oh?)
destrucción                : 1 0 (Oh?)
destrucción                : 10 20 (Oh?)
destrucción                : 2 0 (Oh?)
destrucción                : 1 0 (Oh?)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
fct (a, adr);
```

La firma de esta función es

```
void fct (A, A*);
```

Es decir, recibe un primer parámetro por valor y después un puntero. ¿Cómo se pasa un parámetro por valor? Se hace una copia del mismo. ¿Y cómo se hace una copia del mismo? Se llama al constructor copia.

Resumiendo, cada vez que llamas a `fct` estás haciendo una copia de un objeto de tipo `A`. Por supuesto, este nuevo objeto que se crea dentro de `fct` hay que destruirlo al salir de la función y ahí obtienes la llamada al destructor que te sobra con respecto a tu planteamiento teórico.

¿Se puede evitar esta copia? Sí, para eso inventaron en C++ las `referencias`:

```
void fct (A&, A*)
```

O si el objeto no debe ser modificado dentro de `fct`:

```
void fct(const A&, A*); // versión 1
void fct(A const&, A*); // versión 2
```

Al declarar el objeto como referencia no te obliga a modificar la implementación de la función... únicamente su firma. A nivel interno una referencia se comportará como un puntero... pero sin el engorro de tener que usar un puntero de forma explícita:

- No hay que usar el operador de indirección `->`
- No te entran dudas sobre si debes o no liberar el recurso dentro de la función
- Sabes que siempre te van a pasar un objeto válido (no vale pasar un puntero nulo)

En cuanto a las llamadas a los destructores que ves al final de la ejecución, es el resultado de eliminar los objetos que has creado por valor en `main`. Si cuentas los destructores que te chocan dan 11:

```
A a;                   // 1
A b(2);                // 2
A c(10,20);            // 3
A d = a ;              // 4
A * adr = new A (3,3); // <--- Este no se libera 
// ...
A e(30,40);            // 5
A tab[6]={4,c,0,e};    // 6,7,8,9,10,11
```

Como ves tienes 11 objetos por valor. Cuando la ejecución abandona el ámbito de estas variables se invoca automáticamente a sus destructores para eliminarlas de forma limpia.

¿Por qué no se está llamando al destructor del objeto que hemos creado con `new`? En este caso el problema viene determinado por el sitio donde se está almacenando cada variable:

- Los objetos por valor se almacenan en la pila o `stack`. Aquí es donde también se almacenan la pila de llamadas a funciones. Al abandonar una función el programa debe limpiar la pila y ahí es donde forzosamente debe eliminar las variables que pertenecen a dicha función.
- Los objetos creados con `new` se almacenan en la memoria dinámica o `heap`. El ámbito de estos objetos no está limitado a la propia función y debe ser el usuario el que se encargue de liberar la memoria asociada de forma manual cuando ya no los necesite. Para facilitar la gestión del ciclo de vida de estos objetos puedes recurrir al uso de punteros inteligentes o `smart pointers`.

Comment: La función `fct` destruye el objeto (`delete`) apuntado por el puntero que recibe en el segundo parámetro; no se si lo has visto.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Cierto, es fácil perderse algun detalle desde el movil. Aun así creo que no voy a modificar la respuesta porque en lo que me quería centrar era en la diferencia entre crear un objeto por valor o por puntero. Gracias por la nota.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que añadas a los logs la dirección de memoria del objeto que estás tratando, usa también la macro `__FUNCTION__` (o mejor `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` si lo tienes disponible), puede ser muy revelador:

```
A::A()
{
    x = 1 ;  y = 0 ;
    cout << __FUNCTION__ << ' ' << x << ' ' << y << " (" << this << ")\n";
}

A::A(int abs)
{
    x = abs ;  y = 0 ;
    cout << __FUNCTION__ << ' ' << x << ' ' << y << " (" << this << ")\n";
}

A::A(int abs, int ord)
{
    x = abs ;  y = ord ;
    cout << __FUNCTION__ << ' ' << x << ' ' << y << " (" << this << ")\n";
}

A::A (const A & a)
{
    cout << __FUNCTION__ << ' ' << x << ' ' << y << " (" << this << ")\n";
    x = a.x ;  y = a.y ;
}

A::~A ()
{
    cout << __FUNCTION__ << ' ' << x << ' ' << y << " (" << this << ")\n";
}
```

Veamos ahora los comportamientos *sOh?rprendentes*:

```
A a;
A * adr = new A (3,3) ;

void fct (A d, A * add)
{
    cout << "entrada fct" << endl ;
    delete add ;
    cout << "salida fct" << endl ;
}
```

En la llamada a `fct` estás llamando el constructor de copia de `A`; estás copiando la instancia `a` en el parámetro `d`, esto provoca tanto el mensaje `constructor IV (de copie) : 1 0 (Oh?)` como el mensaje `destrucción                : 1 0 (Oh?)`.

- `constructor IV (de copie) : 1 0 (Oh?)` se muestra al copiar la instancia `a` en el primer parámetro de `fct` llamado `b`.
- `destrucción                : 1 0 (Oh?)` se muestra al destuir el parámetro `b` de la función `fct`.

En C++ los objetos que son creados en memoria automática (aquellos que no se crean con memoria dinámica, con el operador `new`) son destruidos automáticamente al finalizar su ciclo de vida<sup>1</sup>. El ciclo de vida de estos objetos empieza en su declaración y finaliza al cerrar su ámbito (normalmente al encontrar una llave de cierre `}`).

Así que el parámetro `d` de `fct` empieza su ciclo de vida al abrir las llave de la función `fct` y finaliza al cerrar la llave de la misma función, y es destruido en consecuencia.

De la misma manera las instancias `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` y las seis instancias de `A` contenidas en el arreglo `tab` finalizan su ciclo de vida al salir de la función `main` y **son destruidas en orden inverso al de construcción**:

[Estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (la traducción y resaltado son míos):

> #### 6.6 Instrucciones de salto
>
> ...
>
> 2. Al salir de un ámbito, los objetos con duración de almacenamiento automático que hayan sido construidos en ese ámbito **son destruidos en orden inverso a su construcción**.
>
> #### 12.4 Destructores
>
> ...
>
> 8. Después de ejecutar el cuerpo del destructor y destruir cualquier objeto automático en el mismo, el destructor de la clase `X` llama a los destructores de cualquier miembro no estático de `X`, los destructores de las clases base de `X` y, si `X` es del tipo de la clase más derivada, su destructor llama los destructores de todas las clases base virtuales de `X` [...] **Los destructores de elementos de un arreglo se llaman en orden inverso a su construcción**.

---

<sup>1</sup>Existen excepciones muy específicas a esto como la optimización de valor de retorno y las semánticas de movimiento, pero esos temas dan para otra pregunta.